# Make tag [legislation] a synonym of [law]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[legislation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation): 6 questions

[law](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law): 14 questions

Or is there a subtle difference I don't get?

Comment: I am migrating this question from a guess of the intended site based on the tags' usage counts.

Comment: I think you need to make an edit (any edit) to make the magic tag links point to the right site.

Comment: @Gilles: I posted to the wrong site indeed, this is for OpenData, sorry for the mess and thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Just to clarify: You suggest merging [legislation] into [law], right?

Comment: @PatrickHoefler: Yes that's what I was suggesting. I have no strong opinion about it though.

Answer (score 2):

There are currently no tag wikis for [law](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) or [legislation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) . My initial guess based on current use was:

- [law](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) is used for questions if something is legal or not.
- [legislation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) is used for questions about the law-making process
  itself.

**Update:** In addition, now there's also [legality](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legality).

Thinking about it a little more, I guess one common tag should be enough.

I really like [Phil's suggestion](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291/make-tag-legislation-a-synonym-of-law#302) for using [legal](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) because that should encompass all the other tags, is short and easy to grasp.

If there are no objections, I'll go ahead and merge the three tags into [legal](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal) for now. If desired, we can always rename the tag later.

---

On a related note: If the proposed [Law SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law) makes it into public beta and survives the initial phase, we should think about if we want to outsource our "Is it legal to … ?" questions there, since I have a strong feeling that we don't have too many lawyers or law experts here on Open Data SE. Anyhow, let's cross that bridge when we come to it.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: make [legislation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) a synonym of [law](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law), and then just use [law](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law).

Option 2: combine [legislation](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation) and [law](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/law) into a new tag, [legal](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legal)

(In any case, we should pass the questions over to [Law.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/67858/law))

Comment: +1 for [legal]!